# Code Igniter SubApplication

Tags: codeigniter, subapplication

So, codeigniter has application and system. I want to add another folder called "platform" and it would have the same directory structure as application (controllers, views and everything).

How I want it to work is like this:
- When you load a model, view, library, controller etc it should first check in application (if it's not there, it should check in platform and if it's not there it should show an error)
- I want to make some basic models and controllers in the "platform" and all the controllers and models from "application" to inherit them
- I want to extend basic core and library classes in the "platform" and if needed they would be extended in the "application"

I don't know if code igniter can already do that or if it needs something to do it.

Basically it's something like the plugins from cakephp (if somebody knows how they are/work).

Question:

How do I do the above?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have a question.

Comment: I edited: My question is: How do I do that.

Comment: You can have have 2 "applications" share the same system folder, but they are independent from each other.  To do what you want, you gonna have to edit the `Loader.php` in `system/core`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the "third_party" folder where you can add a "Sub Application" as you call it or a `Application "Package"`.

> "An application package allows for the easy distribution of complete sets of resources in a single directory, complete with its own libraries, models, helpers, config, and language files. It is recommended that these packages be placed in the application/third_party folder..."

Source:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html *(Its almost down at the bottom of the document.)*

This is done inside of the application folder. 
There might be a way to achieve what you want and put your folder outside of the application by doing this:

```
$this->load->add_package_path(PATH_OUTSIDE_APPLICATIONS.'/my_package/');
```

instead of :

```
$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/my_package/');
```

I haven't tested if it would work yet. But you can try it!

Comment: I can't stress enough how awesome this sounds. Will give it a try tomorrow :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some rejigging of files, but you could create two folders with separate applications files, and then point two separate index files to each folder with the $application_folder variable.

I've never actually tried this, but it should work. Make sure you also update the $system_folder var.

More here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html